# Freeing memory from a binary tree in C

Tags: c, memory, binary-tree

I looked at this answer and I am sure I'm using it correctly but my while loop never ends.

My code recursivly removes the bottom level of the tree. At least I think it does. Here's the code:

```
void freeTree(node *tree){
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Free Tree\n");//Start here #1
    printf("%i\n", tree->number); //#2
    if(!tree){//The tree is not null so continue
        return;
    }
    while (tree)
    {
        if(tree->left){
            printf("Going Left\n");// why does it go here at the end? #4
            freeTree(tree->left);
        } else if (tree->right)
        {
            printf("Going right\n");
            freeTree(tree->right);
        } else if (tree->right == NULL && tree->left == NULL)//Check if bottom of the tree
        {
            printf("Freed: %i\n", tree->number);// #3
            tree = NULL;
            free(tree);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

My output in my terminal looks like this:

```
Free Tree
5
Freed: 5
Going Left
```

I don't understand how after freeing the node in my while loop it tries to free the node by `Going Left` in the console.

What am I missing or messing up here?

Comment: You should free tree before setting it to null. This is not the culprit but it’s a memory leak.

Comment: If I free it first I get a malloc error. `pointer being freed was not allocated`

Comment: `printf("%i\n", tree->number);  if(!tree){` That's undefined behaviour in the case that `tree` is NULL. The `if` needs to go before the `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s follow the steps of the while loop. First we check if the tree has a left node. Assuming it does we take pointer to the node and call the function on it. Then, assuming function finished successfully we skip other conditions and go through the loop again. This time the pointer to the left node is still there but the memory it points to is freed. That is our first bug – dangling pointer.
Second bug is the infinite loop. Because the condition never changes when in the loop (left node pointer stays set).
To mitigate both issues you should set the left node pointer to null right after calling the function on it.

Same would happen with the right node (assuming program does not get stuck on the left node.

And finally, if both nodes are null, the pointer to tree set to null leaving a memory leak. And then you call free on the null pointer (which is fine on it own).

---

Generally when working with tree-like structures one would either use recursion or a loop. Using both normally does not make much sense.

P.S.
An interesting fact. It is possible to fix this program by only removing code - the best kind of fix.

Comment: Ahh. So it's the fact that I have it in a while loop that is the problem? I'm going to try it out right now.

Comment: Ok, removing it from the while loop allows all my left node to be deleted. However, it didn't start deleting the right nodes. I'll have to keep playing with this to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Funlamb If you put `if(!tree) return;` at the top of the function, you can remove all conditions. The while loop is not needed anyway.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to delete the right side of the tree. It seems to be only deleting the left branch. It looks as though it gets all the way to the bottom of the left branch then deletes everything there but doesn't go to any of the right branches.

Comment: Wait? I can literally get rid of all conditions? Wow I made this way more complected than it needed to be. I thought checking with the `if` statements was necessary. @wildplasser

Comment: No, It still just goes to the left. @wildplasser

Answer (score -1):

```
void freeTree(node *tree)
{
    if(!tree) return;
    freeTree(tree->left);
    freeTree(tree->right);
    free(tree);

}
```